# How do you build pentagrams?

Tags: dungeons

I have just downloaded the demo of Dungeons and am on the level where you first capture a pentagram and then have to kill heros to get soul power. It then asks me to extend my area of influence by building pentagrams, but I have no idea how.

I cannot find an icon or keyboard shortcut or anything on how to build a pentagram. I hope I dont just have to capture pentagrams because I cannot find any others on the map either...

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

On the top right corner of your screen you have 5 icons. If I remember correctly, the second one is the pentagram's menu. There you have to chose which pentagrams (which monster) you want.
Hope it helps :)